# Trying to replicate default action dialog buttons

Tags: android, text, android-alertdialog

I've created a custom action dialog, however for the buttons i'd like to replicate the default Android ones, but can't seem to get it right.

Is there a way if i can check the default textsize, font style, if it's bold, ect ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of informations on this site:
https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#theming

Hope you will find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend an AlertDialog you can specify which theme to use by calling the following constructor.

```
protected AlertDialog(@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes int themeResId)
```

In order to replicate the default button style you can try to extend the default theme for an AppCompat AlertDialog and then pass it to your custom one.

```
<style name="MyCustomAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Optionally you can customize other attributes -->
</style>
```

-

```
public class MyCustomAlertDialog extends android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog {
    private MyCustomAlertDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.MyCustomAlertDialogStyle);
        // ...
    }
}
```